# Where like in Laravel - column not found:1054

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, sql-like

I'm using Laravel. I make MySQL query for a search. I want to search in two columns. First, I've used:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"
```

But after that I decided, it's better use:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE ".$search."
```

in this way, search results would be better and exact.
But when I search for example word "education", it's throwing Queryexception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'education' in 'where clause - ...WHERE column_name LIKE education'

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Post your actual code which runs the query. Including any query builder or model calls.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes for string value:

```
WHERE column_name LIKE '".$search."'
```

Query will looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ... WHERE column_name LIKE '" . $search . "' ... ";
```

Comment: I also tried this, but now it's endless loop - The page isn't redirecting properly. My query looks like: "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE first_column LIKE ' ". $search.  " '   OR second_column LIKE ' ". $search. " ' ...". It was working width % but I can't find why it's endless loop without it.

Comment: Where is endless loop? Please share more code, where it can be

Comment: Now, I dd my query and it returns null when I write it without %. If I use % it's working.

Comment: `LIKE '" . $search . "'` is equal to `= '" . $search . "'`. So, what value of `$search` you testing? And what data found? And what you need to find?

Comment: When I use LIKE ```'%" . $search . "%'``` - it's working. When I use: ```LIKE '" . $search . "'``` it returns null. I'm searching words in title and content columns in database. Problem is that when I search for example word "some" I want to show only title and content that contain this word, but it shows title and content that are for example word "something". How to make like query to find exact words?

Comment: Use FULLTEXT index on `column_name` and `MATCH() AGAINST()` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. But maybe it will be fine to use wildcards, or substr() to search for ```'%" . $search . "%'``` only to space .

Comment: Maybe. But i worry what may be different situations, not only spaces: `some `, `some.`, `:some`, `some-` and other.

Comment: It's giving me: "The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes " when I tried to add FULLTEXT indexes.

Comment: If your table is InnoDB, it will works for MySQL 5.6 and up

Comment: I did it in this way: ```   WHERE title  REGEXP '[[:<:]]".$search."[[:>:]]'```. Maybe php version is less than 5.6. Thank you for your help!